# How to make this nested SQL 'group by' query work?

Tags: php, sql, group-by, subquery

The following SQL-Query is not working and results in an error. How it should be modified to work as expected?

```
mysql_query("SELECT * from 
                     (SELECT * from dist WHERE Date='$_POST[date]' and Time='$_POST[time]' 
                     group by Part, Subject, Room) 
             WHERE Room='$ss2a[Room]'  
");
```

Comment: what error is there?

Comment: Please add the **error message** and TAG the `RDBMS` you are using

Comment: show your table strucutre

Comment: I am using phpmyadmin sql database . mysql_num_rows(above query) gives 'mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\examsem\qr1.php on line 73'

Comment: Refined title to sound more specific, reformulated some description, reformatted code snippet, added tags.

Answer (score 0):

There were a few issues in the sql - most notably the use of array variables within the statement - these were not being accessed correctly within a quoted string. Also, the final where clause appeared to have a constant though I suspect that should have been a string - on closer inspection, all `$_POST[var]` instances failed to use quoted names ~ should be `$_POST[$var]` or `$_POST['var']`

To access array variables within a quoted string ( or certain other types of data also ) encapsulate within curly braces.

Also, field names such as `Date` and `Time` are not really valid - so you should encapsulate those in backticks.

```
mysql_query("select * from (
        select * from dist where `Date`='{$_POST['date']}' and `Time`='{$_POST['time']}' group by `Part`, `Subject`, `Room`
    ) tbl where  `Room`='{$ss2a['Room']}';");
```

Though I'm not sure I can see a reason why you need the nested select statement

Comment: There is a missing alias name here  `..) where..` should be `..) A where..`